# ¿Cómo hacer un menú flotante?

Tags: html, css

Dispongo de un proyecto web que me dispongo a acabar, y hay algunas cositas que me faltan.
Tengo un desplegable/flotante donde manejo los idiomas de la página web. En la vista de móvil se puede manejar bien, pero en la vista de ordenador me surge el problema de que no puedo desplegar el menú. Es como si terminara donde termina el div. ¿Habría alguna opción de que se mostrara completo?

Enseño código:

```
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle navbar-right" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsibleNavbar">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" th:href="@{/}"><img  class="img-responsive imagen" th:src="@{/images/Logo_web.jpg}"></a>
            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapsibleNavbar">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav centro vista">
                    <li><a th:href="@{/about}" th:text="#{header.navbar.about}"></a></li>
                    <li><a th:href="@{/shop}" th:text="#{header.navbar.shop}"></a></li>
                    <li><a th:href="@{/list}" th:text="#{header.navbar.list}"></a></li>
                    <li sec:authorize="hasRole('ADMIN')"><a th:href="@{/userslist}" th:text="#{header.navbar.userslist}"></a></li>
                    <li><a th:href="@{/gallery}" th:text="#{header.navbar.gallery}">Galer&iacute;a</a></li>
                    <li>
                        <div class="dropdown">
                            <button class="btn btn-primary "
                                type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-flag"></span>
                                <span th:text="#{header.navbar.language}" th:remove="tag"></span>
                                <span class="caret"></span>
                            </button>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li>
                                    <a href="?language=es">
                                        <p th:text="#{header.navbar.language.spanish}"></p>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="?language=en">
                                        <p th:text="#{header.navbar.language.english}"></p>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <div sec:authorize="isAnonymous()">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right centro">
                        <li>
                            <a class="btn btn-success" th:href="@{/login}" th:text="#{header.navbar.login}"></a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div sec:authorize="isAuthenticated()">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right centro">
                        <li>
                            <a class="sesioniniciada"><span th:text="${#authentication.principal.nombre}"></span></a>
                            <a class="btn btn-info" th:href="@{/logout}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-off"></span> <span th:text="#{header.navbar.logout}" th:remove="tag"></span></a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

Aquí es donde está el menú dela web, con la sección de los idiomas. Está en un archivo separado del resto de archivos html que serían el contenido de las secciones de mi web.

[image: Y así es como se ve]

Y así es como se ve. La otra opción de idioma que es inglés no aparece. Cosa que en la vista de móvil si que se puede cambiar entre ambas opciones.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Desconozco si es por la versión de bootstrap que estoy utilizando. En el css la clase del menú, '.dropdown', lo tengo tal que así:

```
.dropdown>li {
    position: relative;
}
```

Y aún así no consigo hacer que sea desplegable. ¿Que opción tengo de poder hacerlo desplegable?